# Show and hide Blade table rows with Alpine JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I am using Blade with Laravel 8.x and would like to show or hide table rows using `x-show` in Alpine JS (v3).

```html
<table>
  @foreach($items as $item)
  <div x-data="{show: false}">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" x-on:click="show = !show">
          Toggle Show
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr x-show="show">
      <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

When I do this however, I get a `ReferenceError: show is not defined` error. Is this approach possible without using `x-for` as I would like to still have access to the Blade variables within the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot place `<div>` element in a `<table>` element. When browser executes your code, it places the `<div>` outside `<table>` element, so in `<tr>` the `show` is not defined.

You can workaround this by replacing `<div>` tag with `<tbody>` or making the button and item name in one row as separate `<td>` and appending `x-data` to `<tr>`.